# How to set the date format on wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl

Tags: wxpython

I am using the wxPython wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl and it presents the dates as "mm dd yyyy". I want "dd mm yyyy". How can I do this? I can see nothing in the [docs](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl.html?highlight=datepicker#wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl)

if I use "date" on the command line (nix), I get

> Sat  2 Jul 14:15:03 BST 2022

```
import wx
import wx.adv
import datetime

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Title = 'Date format'

        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        date_picker = wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl(self)
        date_picker.SetValue(datetime.date.today())

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(date_picker)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wx_app = wx.App()
    MainFrame()
    wx_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It's a widget that extols American exceptionalism above and beyond international standards. :(

Comment: Thanks - I guess I need a wx.CalendarCtrl then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As time has progressed I have realised that there is a distinct need for a more flexible version of this control. I have written a control that allows the date to be picked from a dialog that uses a wx.adv.CalendarCtrl.

The initial value of the date in the control can be set using the *date* property and the format using the *format* property. Changes to the date can be captured in the event *EVT_DATE_CHANGED*; the date is in *event.attr1* of of the event handler.

[image]

[image]

I have included the code for the *DatePicker* and also for a screen to test it

**datepicker.py**

```
import wx, wx.adv
import  wx.lib.newevent
import datetime

BORDER = 5

date_change_event, EVT_DATE_CHANGED = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class DatePicker(wx.Panel):
    """A date picker control."""
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self._format = '%Y-%m-%d'
        self._date = datetime.datetime.today()
        date_str = self._date.strftime(self.format)

        self.txt_date = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.txt_date.SetValue(date_str)
        btn_date = wx.Button(self, label='...')
        btn_date.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.show_dialog)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.txt_date, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=BORDER)
        sizer.Add(btn_date)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(sizer, flag=wx.ALL, border=BORDER)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)

    def show_dialog(self, event):
        """Show the dialog and update the textctrl."""
        date_dialog = _DateDialog(self)
        with date_dialog:
            if date_dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
                return
        if date_dialog.date:
            self._date = date_dialog.date
            self._set_date_value()
            evt = date_change_event(attr1=self._date)
            wx.PostEvent(self, evt)

    @property
    def format(self):
        return self._format

    @format.setter
    def format(self, value):
        """Set the date format in standard form."""
        self._format = value
        if self._date:
            self._set_date_value()

    @property
    def date(self):
        return self._date

    @date.setter
    def date(self, value):
        """Set the date."""
        if not isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
            return
        self._date = value
        if self._date:
            self._set_date_value()

    def _set_date_value(self):
        """Set the value of txt_date."""
        date_str = self._date.strftime(self._format)
        self.txt_date.SetValue(date_str)


class _DateDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.date = None
        self.Title = 'Select date'
        self.calendar = wx.adv.CalendarCtrl(self, date=parent.date)
        self.calendar.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_CALENDAR_SEL_CHANGED, self.date_change)
        button_sizer = self.CreateButtonSizer(wx.OK | wx.CANCEL)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.calendar, flag= wx.BOTTOM, border=BORDER)
        sizer.Add(button_sizer, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(sizer, flag=wx.ALL, border=BORDER)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(main_sizer)

    def date_change(self, event):
        date_format = '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'
        date_str = self.calendar.GetDate()
        date = date_str.Format(date_format)
        self.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, date_format)
```

**test_datepicker.py**

```
"""Display a DatePicker object."""
import wx
from datepicker import DatePicker


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Title = 'Test DatePicker'
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        date_picker = DatePicker(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(date_picker)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wx_app = wx.App()
    MainFrame()
    wx_app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

since wxPython aims at a **truly native user interface** the control uses the users system format (on Windows f.i. *Time & Language, Regional format data*)

Comment: Not on *nix!. And Rolf's response

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).